# Config.LOGD return false instead true

Tags: android, logging, config

I have a code like this:

```
if (Config.LOGD) Log.d(TAG, "foo");
```

The question is: why I dont see this log n my logcat?
I have android 2.2
As I know `Config.LOGD` must be const `true`

Comment: Do you see it without the `if (Config.LOGD)`?

Comment: Of course. But it was a problem because I hadn't ability to edit this code.)

Comment: I was indeed wrong saying it defaults false.

But back to the question, assuming you cannot build the project and is using an APK provided by someone else, it may be using an old SDK version where `Config.LOGD` was working as intended and returning false for a release build.

Comment: It was our app. It was necessary to understand why we didn't receiving logs from users! Documentation and reality are different)